# My job is to write a function which increments a string, to create a new string

Tags: python-3.x, string

> Why my code is wrong which outputs an error

```
def increment_string(strng):
   
    if strng == '':
        return '1'
    elif strng.isdigit():
        number= int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit,strng)))
        return re.sub('\d+',str(number +1),strng)

    
    return strng + str(1)
```

Output:
increment_string("foobar001")

It should return 'foobar002' but it is returning 'foobar0011'

Answer (score 1):

It gives 'foobar0011' because the program control is not entered into the `elif` block and it returned `strng + str(1)`.

Program control not entered the `elif` block because the function `strng.isdigit()` returns false. This returns true only if each character in `strng` is a digit. My suggestion is to replace `isdigit()` function with the `isalnum()` function. Because `isalnum()` function verifies that each character in a string is either an alphabet or a digit.

Here is my solution :

```
import re

def increment_string(strng):
   
    if strng == '':
        return '1'

    elif strng.isalnum():
        number = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, strng)))
        return re.sub('\d+', str(number + 1), strng)

    return strng + str(1)

print(increment_string("foobar001"))
```

Comment: it must pass other cases also like if the input is 'foobar'                                                             it is printing error message invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is explained below:

```
def increment_string(strng):
    #...
    ''' 
    this is checking if the passed string is a digit. Since you are
    passing "foobar001", which is not a digit, elif condition is not executed,
    and goes directly to the last return statement where you simple add "1" to the string
    '''
    elif strng.isdigit():
        #...
    
    return strng + str(1)
```

To meet the requirements given in the question, try this out:

```
def increment_string(strng):
    match = re.search('(\d+)', strng)
    if match:
        num = match.group(1)
        newNum = str(int(num) + 1)
        return re.sub('\d+', str(newNum.zfill(len(num))), strng)
    else:
        return strng
```

Note : This returns the same input string in case no number is present.

To know more about zfill, check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp).

Comment: Thats cool, but what is happening with the above code.

Comment: i was asking about my code, your code is superlike, i understood from the very beginning,as i'm learning for bit by bit,can you elaborate why my code is not working

Comment: You can refer the answer.

Comment: if i am making str.isalphnum(), it should exit from elif statement and the string should add  the number, why it is taking number which is inside elif statement and adding it to the that is being returned outside the statement.